# Gmail API seems to round up the timestamp of messages to minutes

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I am using Google Apps Script to do something with Gmail messages. To retrieve messages within a specific time range, I use the GmailApp search method. It seems that Gmail will round up the timestamp of the messages to minutes so I could not get results which I would expect to have.

Let's say we have 3 messages with timestamps

- 2020-10-15 11:14:41
- 2020-10-15 11:38:49
- 2020-10-15 11:59:26

When I search the messages by query "after:1602759600 before:1602730800" (from 2020-10-15 11:00:00 to 2020-10-15 12:00:00), only 2 messages were returned. It seems that Gmail rounds up the timestamp of the messages to minutes, where the "11:59:26" message was treated as "12:00" (It also appears as "12:00" in the inbox of the Gmail page)

If I set the query to "after:1602730800 before:1602766800" (from 2020-10-15 12:00:00 to 2020-10-15 13:00:00), the message stamped with "2020-10-15 11:59:26" returned as the search result.

To investigate this, I sent another 2 messages to see how Gmail rounds up. I sent the messages at 12:59:15 and 12:59:45 respectively, this time Gmail rounds down the "12:59:15" to "12:59" and the "12:59:45" to "13:00".

Does anybody knows what is behind the box?

Comment: Does  the query work properly in the user interface of gmail? Maybe related: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36758991

Comment: It works exactly the same way where Gmail.search does. Only 2 messages appear when I paste "after:1602759600 before:1602730800" into the search box of the gmail UI, and the missing one appears when I do "after:1602730800 before:1602766800" search.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. I tested it with a message of mine, and the search seems to work with a precision of seconds, in the UI, in the API and in the Apps Script method. Where did you get those timestamps? Are the timezones being applied correctly?

Comment: It'll be easier for others to reproduce, if you add both the send email code and GmailApp.search code. PS: Also, use `@` to reply like `@iamblich`